# QtDesigner печать таблицы

Tags: python, pyqt5

есть одна проблема. Я пытаюсь распечатать таблицу, но пишет ошибку атрибута,

```
self.Ui_MainWindow.print_(printer)
AttributeError: 'Ui_MainWindow' object has no attribute 'Ui_MainWindow'
```

"TextEdit" печатает без проблем. Я не могу понять в чем дело, если есть возможность, пожалуйста, подскажите мне. Вот пример кода:

```
def print_file(self):
    printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
    dialog = QPrintDialog(printer, self)


    if dialog.exec_() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
        self.Ui_MainWindow.print_(printer)
```

Comment: Может Вам просто нарисовать изображение, а потом распечатать его? Зачем использовать для этого PyQt5?

Comment: Нет, это таблица будет заполняться пользователем, а затем нужно ее распечатать

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Может Вам сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил данные в таблицу, а затем автоматически выполняется команда Alt+PrtScr(используйте для этого PyAutoGui) и получившиеся изображение печатается. Как Вам?

Comment: Большое спасибо за предложение, но к сожалению заказчика так не устраивает, есть рабочий пример с другими функциями, но почему- то он не работает в моей таблице.